Finding an upper bound for / computing a $d$-dimensional integral
I want to know if there is a clever way of computing this $d$-dimensional integral, or if and how it is possible to use polar coordinates?
\begin{align}
                \int_{|m|\leq k_F} d^d m \left( \ \int_{|n|\geq k_F} d^d n \ \frac{\chi_{[0,B]}\left(|n-m|\right)}{(|n|-|m|+k_F^{-1})}\right)^2\, 
\end{align}
with $B, k_F >0$ and $\chi_{[0,B]}$ being the characteristic function.
Is it possible to find a good upper bound in terms of $k_F$?
